# Comic about two brothers where one of them sometimes changes into a wolf

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read a (Belgian?) comic series a very long time ago ( at least 20 years ago) about two brothers (twins?), one of whom sometimes transformed into a wolf named Isengrim (with dark red eyes) with its own personality and goals, but still had a good relationship with his human sibling and undertook adventures together.

And yes, can't find it on google.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this an entire publication about the twins, or a story in a collection?  If the former, was it part of a series?

Comment: Was the sibling named "Reynard" or some variation on that?  [Reynard the Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynard_the_Fox)'s primary antagonist/foil is named Isengrim and that's a classic (12th century) story.

Comment: @davidw IIRC no, the two siblings had very simple names, like "Bob"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I've managed to find it, it's called 'Yvain et Yvon' in French, and 'Isegrims Abenteuer' in German (not sure about the Dutch title), and was written by Patrick Cadot.

It was published in Tintin/Kuifje magazine in Belgium, which is probably where you found it (and where I remembered it from), though it was also published by Yps in Germany, which is the [one place I've found that actually has information on it](https://www.ypsfanpage.de/comics/isegrim.php).

Not sure how to provide excerpts in this case, but I'll try linking images, so you can see if it's familiar to what you've read:

[image: Jonas and Isengrim, beneath a tree on a high river bank, look out at a town on the other side of the river]

[image: Jonas hugging Isengrim]

Some quotes, on DavidW's recommendation. Still in German, since doing a fully correct English translation is a bit too difficult for me:

> Die pfiffigen Zwillinge Jonas und Juri sind alles andere als normale Kinder, denn Juri besitzt die Fähigkeit sich in einen Wolf zu verwandeln. Als Wolf Isegrim besitzt er magische Fähigkeiten...
>
> [The bright **twins Jonas and Juri** are normal in every way except that Juri has the ability to **turn into a wolf**.  As **the wolf Isengrim** he has magical abilities...]
>
> <sub><sup>rough translation by DavidW; errors mine</sup></sub>

> Juri und Jonas sind zwei ganz normale pfiffige und liebe Zwillinge, die sich gut verstehen. Sie sind aben­teuer­lustig und gelangen dadurch manchmal sogar in gefährliche Situationen. Juris unglaubliche Ge­heim­nis teilen die Zwillinge nur mit ihren besten Freunden und nur, wenn es wirklich sein muss. Selbst ihre Eltern wissen nichts davon.
>
> [Juri and Jonas are two completely normal, bright, and loving twins in synch with one another. They are eager for adventure and sometimes end up in dangerous situations. The twins only share Juri's unbelievable secret with their best friends, and only when they truly need to.  Even their parents don't know.]
>
> <sub><sup>rough translation by DavidW; errors mine</sup></sub>

> Isegrim, dem Wolf mit den glühend roten Augen, umgibt ein Geheimnis: Er ist immer da, wenn Juri verschwunden ist: Isegrim ist Juri und Juri ist Isegrim!
>
> [**Isengrim, the wolf with glowing red eyes**, has a secret:  He's always there when Juri disappears:  Isengrim is Juri and Juri is Isengrim!]
>
> <sub><sup>rough translation by DavidW; errors mine</sup></sub>

Edit 2: Found the Dutch title: 'Ed en Ad'

Comment: You should also provide some quotes that show how it matches.  E.g. "**Juri und Jonas sind** zwei ganz normale pfiffige und liebe **Zwillinge**, die sich gut verstehen." "**Isegrim, dem Wolf mit den glühend roten Augen**, umgibt ein Geheimnis: Er ist immer da, wenn Juri verschwunden ist: **Isegrim ist Juri und Juri ist Isegrim**!"

Comment: Ah, true, thanks. Translating them properly might be tricky though, my German is rather rusty (and the less said about my French, the better). So I'll be leaving the quotes in German for now. Any translation edits would be welcome.

Comment: It'd be fine to use Google's translation feature. Just mention that that's what you did, so anyone reading your answer can take that into account.

Comment: Managed to find the Dutch name as well.

Also, apologies to the mod, logged in through a different stack exchange, so when I reached this one I had been logged out and didn't notice, so when I initially tried to edit it in it showed as an anonymous edit.